# Run a twisted trial test within a program

Tags: python, testing, twisted, trial

I would like to write a python program that runs a twisted test without having to run the program as a test.

I know it might sound a bit weird, but the program is intended to simulate a twisted connection rather than offering a real one to a user.

My motivation is to use the properties of twisted trial tests inside the program (especially the  control on the reactor `Clock` object that allows me to simulate the passing of time).

I've written the code for the test following the twisted event-driven guide and now I want to integrate it in a program.

Is it possible? Is it something that somebody has already done before? (couldn't find info) What the best way to do it?

Comment: `Clock` is independent of trial.  Are you sure you need to run all of the test framework stuff for what you want to do.  You can just write code that uses `Clock` (or ... put another way ... code that uses IReactorTime ... whether that's `Clock` or something else) directly.

Comment: I also need `StringTransport` from `test.proto_helpers`. And then, I would need to run the reactor in a similar way to which the tested framework does. Is it as simple as running the reactor like `reactor.run()`, or do I have to do something else?

Comment: Wellllllll.... the way trial runs the reactor is crazy and super complicated and probably also dumb and should be changed except hysterical raisins...  Note that neither `Clock` nor `StringTransport` requires the reactor to be running in order to work correctly, though.

Comment: but I'm using this trick: `reactor.callLater = self.clock.callLater`. I also assumed I would also need to run the reactor running to trigger delayed calls such as `callLater` and so on... isn't it right?

Comment: That looks like a very bad trick.  Maybe ... don't do it?  If you monkey-patch objects from a library then you're pretty much heading off on your own.  It's difficult to offer advice about how to use the libary if you've *changed* how the library works in an unknown way.

Comment: I was inspired by this trick from official Twisted documentation on test-driven programming with twisted: `self.proto.callLater = self.clock.callLater`,  https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/trial.html#testing-scheduling. I'm doing this because there are calls that are not in the protocol that I also want to control with the clock...

Comment: That's not a very good example.  Twisted docs kind of suck.  However, a random protocol's (application code under test) "callLater" method isn't the same as the global reactors' "callLater" method.  Don't monkey-patch the reactor like this.

Comment: Functions take arguments.  Pass your Clock instance to some functions.  Call methods on it.

Comment: Yes, but the normal behaviour of those functions is not to use clock but to use the reactor. I want to use clock for a special case such as testing or simulating...

Comment: Perhaps the normal behavior of the functions is wrong, then?  A common testing saw is "If it's hard to test, it's probably wrong".